# Pasting excel rich text column into Sharepoint 2013 list edit view

Tags: 2013, list, list-view, custom-list, excel

I was trying to paste an excel table to SP2013 datasheet view with one of the column is enhanced rich text editor. But the view stripped out the styling from excel table.

Excel table:
[image: Excel table]

This is the result of the pasted text:
[image: SP List view]

Any thoughts on this guys?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to use Rich Text and Enhanced Rich Text in a SharePoint list.  First, you need to make sure the column is set up appropriately. (`List Settings` -> Click on column name -> Make sure it is Multi Line of Text column and that at least Rich Text is allowed).

Copying the formatting directly from Excel doesn't work but you are able to format it after it is in the list.

Comment: I see. So there is no way to paste the pre-formatted text directly into SP2013 list?

Comment: You can paste it in with the HTML attached and it will work (i.e. `<b>Hello World</b>` or `<i>This will paste in italic</i>`), but otherwise I don't believe there is a way.

Answer (score -1):

SharePoint 2013 handle only some column types like: 1 line of text, multiple lines of text, number, date, ... but not the style of text. To make bold text in a SharePoint table, you can modify the CSS of the page.

Comment: It is surely possible to create a SharePoint field that handles rich text markup. See for example here http://stevemannspath.blogspot.se/2013/10/sharepoint-2013-adding-rich-text-column.html